# Delete duplicate rows, except last occurance - VBA Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I need to fine tune my code to delete all duplicates except last occurance. Duplicates will be defined by multiple columns (Column A, B, C). Next columns have always different numbers so will be ignored in defining duplicates. I need to delete whole row. Also filtering and doing cell next to cell comparison will not work because then it will not know which one was last occurance.
[See example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLEul.jpg)

```
Sub DuplicateDelete()
Dim Rng     As Range
Dim Dn      As Range
Dim nRng    As Range
Dim Q       As Variant
Dim K       As Variant
With Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Rng = .Range(.Range("A9:C9"), .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 End With
  On Error Resume Next
  Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Resize(, Columns.Count).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
For Each Dn In Rng
    If Dn <> "" Then
    If Not .Exists(Dn.Value) Then
        .Add Dn.Value, Array(Nothing, Dn)
    Else
        Q = .Item(Dn.Value)
            If nRng Is Nothing Then
                Set Q(0) = Q(1)
                Set Q(1) = Dn
                Set nRng = Q(0)
            Else
                Set Q(0) = Q(1)
                Set nRng = Union(nRng, Q(0))
                Set Q(1) = Dn
            End If
        .Item(Dn.Value) = Q
      End If
End If
Next
If Not nRng Is Nothing Then
nRng.EntireRow.Delete
End If
End With
End Sub
```

For example in list above, I need 2 rows on top to be deleted, as they are duplicate of last 2 rows. I just need a scanner that would scan all rows and decide to delete all duplicates except their last occurance. Can it be possible? Appreciate your helps in advance.

*Note: This is not my own code, I am beginner level in VBA, it is referened from searches.

Comment: Could you add the code that you're trying to 'fine tune' please.

Comment: Added in above.

Comment: What is the actual last used column in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add Temp Column
2. Fill Temp Column with number series
3. Sort Temp Column Descending
4. Clear Temp Column
5. Remove Duplicates
6. Add Temp Column
7. Fill Temp Column with number series
8. Sort Temp Column Ascending
9. Clear Temp Column

---

```
Sub RevRemoveDuplicates(SheetIndex As Integer, Optional FIRSTRANGE As String = "A9:J9")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Target As Range, TempColumn As Range

    With Worksheets(SheetIndex)
        Set Target = .Range(FIRSTRANGE, .Range(FIRSTRANGE).End(xlDown))
        Set TempColumn = Target.Offset(0, Target.Columns.Count).Resize(, 1)

        With TempColumn
            .Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
            .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, Step:=1, Trend:=False
            .EntireRow.Sort Key1:=.Cells(1, 1), Order1:=xlDescending
            .Clear
        End With
        Target.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlNo

        With TempColumn
            .Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
            .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, Step:=1, Trend:=False
            .EntireRow.Sort Key1:=.Cells(1, 1), Order1:=xlAscending
            .Clear
        End With
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: attached my final code, similar logics, in slightly different way.

Comment: @Marshall Great Idea sorting the data backwards.  I updated my answer to this approach. **Notes:** If you have blank cells in the end of Column A then you'll have to adjust the way that the `Target` range is determined.

Comment: Amazing to see how many different solutions there are to this task. Good post.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious, but wouldn't you just loop from the bottom up and if you come across value combinations that you've already met, then delete that row.

If you used a `Collection` you could create a string key of your 3 values, eg "173|4566|3" and if that key already existed you know you have a duplicate.

Also, it can be quicker to delete rows in one batch rather than a line at a time.

All in all, then, your code could be:

```
Const START_ROW As Long = 9
Dim v As Variant
Dim i As Long, r As Long
Dim key As String
Dim delRows As Range
Dim uniques As Collection
Dim exists As Boolean

' Read the values into an array
With Sheet1
    v = .Range(.Cells(START_ROW, "A"), _
               .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) _
               .Resize(, 3).Value2
End With

Set uniques = New Collection

For i = UBound(v, 1) To 1 Step -1

    key = CStr(v(i, 1)) & "|" & _
          CStr(v(i, 2)) & "|" & _
          CStr(v(i, 3))
    exists = False

    'Test if key exists
    On Error Resume Next
    exists = uniques(key)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If exists Then 'we have a duplicate to be deleted
        r = i + START_ROW - 1
        If delRows Is Nothing Then
            Set delRows = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1)
        Else
            Set delRows = Union(delRows, Sheet1.Cells(r, 1))
        End If
    Else 'we have a new unique item
        uniques.Add True, key
    End If

Next

'Delete the duplicate rows
If Not delRows Is Nothing Then
    delRows.EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Very clever adding `True` to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answers. Sorry could not reply sooner, had a bit of connectivity problems yesterday, so tried few things myself. I ended up using the similar logic in slightly different way. Made the one below where I flip data table upside down completely, then use the excel's built in "remove duplicates" function, then flip data back again. This let me to keep the last occurance as I wanted.

*It is a loop function for every sheet of workbook.*

```
Function Dup_removal_Repeat_all_sheets(i)
'first flip data tables upside down, as excel's duplicate delete works
  'only downwards, but we want to keep latest duplicate addition
    Dim vTop As Variant
    Dim vEnd As Variant
    Dim iStart As Integer
    Dim iEnd As Integer
    Sheets(i).Select
         Range("A10:J10").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        iStart = 1
        iEnd = Selection.Rows.Count
        Do While iStart < iEnd
            vTop = Selection.Rows(iStart)
            vEnd = Selection.Rows(iEnd)
            Selection.Rows(iEnd) = vTop
            Selection.Rows(iStart) = vEnd
            iStart = iStart + 1
            iEnd = iEnd - 1
        Loop
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Now scan top to bottom to delete duplicates
         Range("A10:J10").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$10:$J$2000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
        Header:=xlNo
'Flip data tables back
         Range("A10:J10").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        iStart = 1
        iEnd = Selection.Rows.Count
        Do While iStart < iEnd
            vTop = Selection.Rows(iStart)
            vEnd = Selection.Rows(iEnd)
            Selection.Rows(iEnd) = vTop
            Selection.Rows(iStart) = vEnd
            iStart = iStart + 1
            iEnd = iEnd - 1
        Loop
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

The only problem with this, it will wipe formulas in all table cells, a workaround I did was exclude 1st row from the process (row 9), then at the end of process, autofill it down to last row of data, in all columns. And for the duplicate scan, I gave arbitrary value of 2000 rows (which will not be case, but just not to have to edit it in future).